# Why SyntaxNet demo.sh is not finding correct imports?

Tags: python, tensorflow, syntaxnet

I went through https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet and did everything it says.

I ran this to test:

```
bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names \
    syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
```

I could only make 6 test pass and 6 fails.

But when I run the demo, I am getting error.

```
User:syntaxnet hk$ echo "Parsey McParseface is my favorite parser" | syntaxnet/demo.sh

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/git/models/syntaxnet/bazel-bin/syntaxnet/conll2tree.runfiles/syntaxnet/conll2tree.py", line 20, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/git/models/syntaxnet/bazel-bin/syntaxnet/conll2tree.runfiles/external/tf/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/git/models/syntaxnet/bazel-bin/syntaxnet/conll2tree.runfiles/external/tf/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/git/models/syntaxnet/bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval.runfiles/syntaxnet/parser_eval.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "/git/models/syntaxnet/bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval.runfiles/syntaxnet/parser_eval.py", line 23, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/git/models/syntaxnet/bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval.runfiles/external/tf/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/git/models/syntaxnet/bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval.runfiles/external/tf/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/git/models/syntaxnet/bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval.runfiles/external/tf/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/git/models/syntaxnet/bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval.runfiles/external/tf/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError:     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow
```

what's going on? Is the demo.sh looking for those python imports in different place than where it is placed?

Comment: Looks like some modules did not compile properly. You must first see why the 6 tests failed.

Answer (score 3):

Solved. I was missing some of the steps in bazel installation, in particular, 'Getting bash completion'. I thought that was only for 
jdk7.

Answer (score 2):

Try building and testing SyntaxNet once again using the bazel command. I encountered a quite similar error to this where bazel cannot find the python dir on my machine. After several tries of locating the python dir, bazel finished building and testing SyntaxNet with 1 fail test (a localhost error according to bazel), demo.sh works fine.

I tried building and testing Syntaxnet once again and good thing that this time it passed the 12 tests.

```
INFO: Elapsed time: 88.935s, Critical Path: 31.63s
//syntaxnet:arc_standard_transitions_test                       (cached) PASSED in 3.5s
//syntaxnet:beam_reader_ops_test                                (cached) PASSED in 20.6s
//syntaxnet:graph_builder_test                                  (cached) PASSED in 21.4s
//syntaxnet:lexicon_builder_test                                (cached) PASSED in 8.7s
//syntaxnet:parser_features_test                                (cached) PASSED in 0.7s
//syntaxnet:parser_trainer_test                                 (cached) PASSED in 36.4s
//syntaxnet:reader_ops_test                                     (cached) PASSED in 6.0s
//syntaxnet:sentence_features_test                              (cached) PASSED in 1.6s
//syntaxnet:tagger_transitions_test                             (cached) PASSED in 1.6s
//syntaxnet:text_formats_test                                   (cached) PASSED in 8.7s
//util/utf8:unicodetext_unittest                                (cached) PASSED in 5.6s
//syntaxnet:shared_store_test                                            PASSED in 6.0s

Executed 1 out of 12 tests: 12 tests pass.
```

And there's this additional reminder from bazel that might help:

```
There were tests whose specified size is too big. Use the --test_verbose_timeout_warnings command line option to see which ones these are.
```

Hope this helps.